# How compare time on javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to compare the day of the week of the user input and the hour choosed by the user, but it's not working. The first problem is, the dialogflow only accepts time AM and PM, not the 24hours format (I've trying to use the moment JS, but without sucess too...), and the second problem is my conditionals are not working, the robot make the appointment even when I put all those conditionals.
Sorry for my english, can someone help me? :/

```
    // for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));


});
// Enter your calendar ID below and service account JSON below
// Starts with {"type": "service_account",...

 // Set up Google Calendar Service account credentials
 const serviceAccountAuth = new google.auth.JWT({
   email: serviceAccount.client_email,
   key: serviceAccount.private_key,
   scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
 });

 const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
 process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements

 const timeZone = 'America/Buenos_Aires';
 const timeZoneOffset = '-03:00';

 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
   console.log("Parameters", agent.parameters);
   const appointment_type = agent.parameters.especialidade;
   function makeAppointment (agent) {
     // Calculate appointment start and end datetimes (end = +1hr from start)
     //console.log("Parameters", agent.parameters.date);
     const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
     const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
     const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
       'en-US',
       { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone }
     );

    return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_type).then(() => {
       agent.add(`Ok, ${appointmentTimeString} is fine!.`);
     }).catch(() => {
       agent.add(`I'm sorry, there are no slots available for ${appointmentTimeString}.`);
     });
   }

   let intentMap = new Map();
   intentMap.set('marcarconsultas', makeAppointment);
   agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
 });

 function createCalendarEvent (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_type) {
   var time = dateTimeStart.getHours();
   var weekly = dateTimeStart.getDay();
   //adjust timezone
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     calendar.events.list({
       auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
       calendarId: calendarId,
       timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
       timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
     }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
       // Check if there is a event already on the Calendar
       if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
         reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
       } else if (err || time > 17) {
        reject(err || new Error('We are open until 17h'));
       } else if (err || time < 8) {
        reject(err || new Error('We open at 8h'));
       } else if (err || weekly == 0 && weekly == 6) {
        reject(err || new Error('We do not work saturday or sunday'));
       } else if (err || appointment_type == 'cardiologia' || (time < 8 && time > 12) && (weekly != 4)) {
        reject(err || new Error ('Choose an hour between 8h and 12h'));
       } else if (err || appointment_type == 'infectiologia' || (time < 10 && time > 14) && (weekly == 5)) {
        reject(err || new Error ('Choose an hour between 10h and 14h'));
       } else if (err || appointment_type == 'pré-natal' || ( time < 14 && time > 17) && (weekly != 3)) {
        reject(err || new Error ('Choose an hour between 14h and 17h'));
       } else if (err || appointment_type == 'angiologia' || (time < 8 && time > 12) && (weekly != 3)) {
        reject(err || new Error('Choose an hour between 8h and 12h'));
       } else if (err || appointment_type == 'otorrinolaringologia' || (time < 8 && time > 17) && (weekly != 2 && weekly != 4)) {
        reject(err || new Error('Choose an hour between 8h and 17h'));
       }
       else {
         // Create event for the requested time period
         calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
           calendarId: calendarId,
           resource: {summary: appointment_type +' Appointment', description: appointment_type,
             start: {dateTime: dateTimeStart},
             end: {dateTime: dateTimeEnd}}
         }, (err, event) => {
           err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
         }
         );
       }
     });
   });
 }
```

Comment: The string formed by `agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + timeZoneOffset` is not a format supported by ECMAScript and produces an invalid date in Safari and Firefox at least.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I guess this is the only way that Dialogflow use to get an input. Actually, I'm pretty confused with the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can mess with hour thing by using `hour12: false` or `hour12: true` option while converting `toLocaleString`, mentioned in [MozillaWebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

```js
const timeZone = 'America/Buenos_Aires';
const dateTimeStart = new Date();
var hour12 = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
       'en-US',
       { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone, hour24: true }
     );
var hour24 = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
       'en-US',
       { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone, hour12: false }
     );

console.log(hour24)
console.log(hour12)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert to am pm try this function

```
getTime(timestamp) {
      var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
      var hour = date.getHours();
      var minute = date.getMinutes();
      var dayOrNight = false;

      if (hour > 12) {
        hour = hour - 12;
        dayOrNight = true;
      } else if (hour === 12) {
        dayOrNight = true;
      } else if (hour === 0) {
        hour = 12;
        dayOrNight = false;
      } else {
        dayOrNight = false;
      }
      if (minute < 10) {
        minute = `0${minute}`;
      }
      var AMPM = dayOrNight ? "PM" : "AM";
      return `${hour}:${minute} ${AMPM}`;
    }
```

and can you show us what is user input and with what data are you comparing it to

Comment: timestamp*1000 if timestamp in in seconds you need to pass miliseconds for it to work

Comment: The if..else part can be `let dayOrNight = hour > 11; hour = (hour % 12) || 12;`.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit and which if else statement is this for